# setting a worksheet object as module variable, getting error

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I am trying:

1. In module, declare module-scope variables for worksheet object;
2. In `ThisWorkbook` object, set the variables when workbook opens.

The code for each:

Module 1:

```
Option Explicit
Public ws As Worksheet


Function func()
    dim rng as Range
    set rng = ws.Range("namedRange")
    'rest of code ...
end function
```

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sales")
End Sub
```

When I open the workbook, the first run throws an error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

and all times after that, the error is:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate your problem.  See this [image](http://i58.tinypic.com/2s9rfht.jpg) for how I've set up the project.  What line of code highlights when you get the error?

Comment: you need to **`set`** `rng = ws.Range...`

Comment: Me too. I tried your code, and it works fine. Are you sure that is the only code in your `Workbook_Open` event? If yes, I see no reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried your code. And I almost reached the decision that there is no problem!

But after some trial 'the second error' appeared. My observation is:

When you ***add any extra sub or fn or reset your vba code***, that public object variable get destroyed
and you can no longer access it.

FYI: [Reference link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/760409-visual-basic-applications-reset-all-variables.html)